# List of users in specific Active Directory Distribution Group

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of users and some properties about the user from within an active directory group.

**Update:**

Here are the two methods I currently have:

```
    Dim adGroup As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=com")
    Dim adMembers As Object
    Dim objUser As ActiveDirectoryUser
    Dim objUserList As New List(Of ActiveDirectoryUser)
    Dim directoryEntry As DirectoryEntry

    adMembers = adGroup.Invoke("Members", Nothing)

    For Each adMember As Object In CType(adMembers, IEnumerable)
        directoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(adMember)
        objUser = New ActiveDirectoryUser

        objUser.UserId = directoryEntry.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName").Value.ToString()
        objUser.Contract = directoryEntry.Properties.Item("ou").Value.ToString()
        objUser.LastName = directoryEntry.Properties.Item("sn").Value.ToString()
        objUser.FirstName = directoryEntry.Properties.Item("givenName").Value.ToString()
        objUser.Email = directoryEntry.Properties.Item("mail").Value.ToString()

        objUserList.Add(objUser)
    Next
```

The first piece works, though it seems quite inefficient.  My memory usage climbs and climbs as it's executing and I was getting [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c7993182-9ce2-49c2-8a01-047a5d2060f1) error, though it looks like that can be fixed.  The second method:

```
    Dim results As SearchResultCollection
    Dim directoryEntry2 As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com")
    Dim directorySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry2)
    directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000

    directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)" & _
                           "(objectClass=user)" & _
                           "(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=com))"


    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ou")
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
    directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")

    results = directorySearcher.FindAll
```

The result count seems to vary from each execution of the application which I find odd.  I'm not sure if this is a reliable way of getting the users back or if I need to modify something on my search?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IF you can, do upgrade to .NET 3.5 and use the new much improved `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. Great intro for those new classes is found in [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

With this, your job becomes trivial:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "MyGroup");
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> members = group.GetMembers();
```

Does that work for you?

If you cannot use .NET 3.5, you should inspect the `member` property of the group. The group members are *not* stored as children logically underneath the group in hierarchy, so you cannot find them by using a `DirectorySearcher`.

```
DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,OU=All,DC=Domain,DC=com");

foreach(object groupMemberDN in group.Properties["member"])
{
   // grab the group member's DN
}
```

See the [Quick List of C# Code Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817849.aspx) for Active Directory (or the same for [Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms817850)) in the MSDN library for this snippet and more.

**Update:** if you need the **users** belonging to a particular group (since you want to update their properties or something), you could reverse the approach: search for all the users who have a `memberOf` property equivalent to the group's DN:

```
 DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com");
 DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);

 searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,OU=All,DC=Domain,DC=com))";
 // set other properties on the searcher

 foreach(object result in searcher.FindAll())
 {
    // do whatever you need to do with the entry
 }
```

Comment: Looping through the member properties got me close.  I'll still need to pull properties off the member object then (first name, e-mail, etc).  I assume I'll need to cast the groupmemberDN in your example to a specific object type so I can pull properties from it?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I have two questions.  First, you had said that I couldn't get the members by using a directory searcher, so in your updated example I see that I can, so I was hoping you could elaborate on what you meant there.  Second, I am able to get a result by using the directory searcher, but the count in the collection seems to vary each time I run my application, when it should be consistent (nobody is currently being added to the group).

Comment: @Ek0nomik: you **cannot** enumerate a group to find all its members, since a group is **not** a container in AD which you can enumerate over. It doesn't contain its members as child objects.  You can however enumerate a directory branch and find all the users who are member of a specific group.

Comment: thanks,but when my group defined inside an OU,filter not worked,how can i fix it?

Comment: @Mohsen.Sharify: use the proper Distinguished Name for your group - which will include the OU it's in .....

Answer (score 2):

Scope your search wider, wherever the members may be:

```
Dim directoryEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=All,DC=Domain,DC=com")
```

Filter based on group membership:

```
directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)" & _
                             "(objectClass=user)" & _
                             "(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,OU=All,DC=Domain,DC=com))"
```

Comment: You'll probably need to set directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000 if you are widening the scope.

Comment: Still no luck.  I took exactly what you gave, dropped in my specific values, but I'm not getting any results back.

Comment: @Ek0nomik - My original answer had a typo. I think "memberOf" doesn't have a space.

Comment: @marc_s - How is my answer different from what you suggest in the "Update" section of your answer?

Comment: your original post wouldn't have worked.... now that you've corrected it, it's almost the same as mine. I would limit my LDAP filter to objectCategory (single-valued, indexed) and forget about objectClass, generally - but other than that, we're at the same point now.